# xsim problem statement and solution in the same tcolorbox

Tags: xsim

The following result is obtained using the `tcolorbox` package and the `exam` class. Since I'm writing a book, I switched to the `scrbook` class and the `xsim` package. Is it possible to get the same result? To elaborate on this: I'd like the solution to be in the same box as the problem statement (boxed or not boxed). The word **Answer** is typed using `{\bf }`, so it isn't part of the setup.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a minimal working (or non-working) example in the form of a compilable document illustrating the problem. Right now, I'm not sure what the obstacle is. Why can't you use `tcolorbox` with `scrbook`? Off-topic: `\bf` has been deprecated for decades as far as LaTeX is concerned and ought not be used in LaTeX documents at all.

Comment: There's of course no trouble in using ```tcolorbox``` with ```scrbook```. The point is to have some kind of "exercises/solutions" capabilities so you could disable printing all solutions with one command. P.S. I accepted one of the answers in there. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean `exam` used `tcolorbox` automatically, but `xsim` doesn't? You've provided no code for either the `exam` case or the `xsim` case, so people can only try to guess what you're doing. Since you want the solution displayed, half of what `exam` does isn't really needed, so you could probably just use `tcolorbox` for that. I'm not familiar with `xsim`: does it provide something particular you need?

Comment: I want to reproduce the picture shown above using ```xsim```. It is of course possible to do it only ```tcolorbox``` or in ```tcolorbox```+```exam```, but I want to have the capabilities of ```xsim```, such as, for instance, disable the printing of solutions.

Comment: You're much more likely to get help if you provide code for people to work with. I'm not typing all that out and setting up an example just to see whether I can figure something out. The chances are I'd do something differently anyway, so any answer I gave wouldn't actually work for you.